# How to fit jQuery datepicker on a mobile?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to use the [jquery-UI datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) to fit onto a mobile screen. It's just fine on large screens but does not behave responsibly on mobiles. Is there anything I can do with the css to make it fit onto smaller screens? I've made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/2dy7j7pc/1/).

html

```
<div class="col-xs-11 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-centered">
<label for="start"></label>
<input type="text" id="date-picker-input-1" class="" name="start" placeholder="From">
</div>


<div class="col-xs-11 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-centered">
<label for="end"></label>
<input type="text" id="end" name="end" placeholder="To">
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(function() {
    $( "#date-picker-input-1" ).datepicker({

      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#end" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#end" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",

      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#start" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/datepicker/

Comment: Need to know more about how you're managing the screen view. Like: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: You may want to consider adjusting the the initial scale when a mobile device or smaller screen visits your site. This will make the datepicker easier to interact with for users. Or as was suggested, use the jQuery Mobile version versus the jQuery UI version.